# How to use the transformer for inference

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, attention

I am trying to understand the transformer model from [Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf), following [the annotated transformer](http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html).

The architecture looks like this:

[image: transformer]

Everything is essentially clear, save for the output embedding on the bottom right. While training, I understand that one can use the actual target as input - all one needs is to

- shift the target by one position to the right
- use a mask to prevent using - say - the $n+k$-th word from the output to learn the $n$-th one

What is not clear to me is how to use the model at inference time. When doing inference, one of course does not have the output - what goes there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A popular method for such sequence generation tasks is [beam search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_search). It keeps a number of K best sequences generated so far as the "output" sequences.

In the original paper different beam sizes was used for different tasks. If we use a beam size K=1, it becomes the [greedy method](http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html#greedy-decoding) in the blog you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it mentioned in the blog post, but without much explanation. If I understand correctly, the greedy method amounts to starting from any random output (all 1 seems to be used in the post), use that to generate the first token, then repeat with the first token to generate the second token and so on. If so, it seems that - unlike in training - decoding in inference happens in a loop, one token at a time, not unlike from what happens with RNN. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Beam search would amount to using the same strategy, but keeping the best k tokens at each step, if I understand correctly. Again, while training can exploit parallelization, it seems that decoding would have to happen serially. Please, tell me if I am missing something

Comment: @AndreaFerretti yes! it has to be done step by step, for generating the first token, we usually initiate the output with a fixed `start_symbol`, like all ones.

Comment: Thank you, everything is clear. I was mislead by the remarks I heard that the transformer is more hardware friendly than usual RNN architectures, due to the fact that it avoids the sequential loop, and in fact that works at training time, just not for inference

Comment: @AndreaFerretti Yea, actually there are two tasks at inference time, evaluation and decoding (like [hmms](http://jedlik.phy.bme.hu/~gerjanos/HMM/node6.html)), for the decoding task I believe we need the loop, for the evaluation task, the transformer model has better parallelism than rnns.

Comment: @dontloo Can you explain a little more about the difference between evaluation and decoding for the transformer? Surely, in order to evaluate the performance of the Transformer, you have to encode the input and then decode the output?

Comment: @jonathanking hi by decoding I meant to generate sequences, by evaluation I meant to test the probability of a given sequence, you may take a look at how it's defined in the context of HMMs http://jedlik.phy.bme.hu/~gerjanos/HMM/node6.html

Comment: Any ideas for how to perform inference with a transformer when the model does not output a probability for each token in the target? If I want to forecast the value of 1 variable 24 hours ahead, the model output is [batch_size, 24, 1], i.e. there is 1 value per output token, not vocab_size values per output token. If I understand correctly, beam search works well in an NLP problem because it is possible to select the k "best" (best = highest probability) tokens, but when the model output is not a probability for each token in the target, it seems to me beam search cannot be used. Any ideas?

Comment: @KasperGL interesting question, I don't know much on that, I think if the scalar output of your model can be interpreted as some probability distribution then there could a way to sample from it, say k samples for each step, then we might be able do something similar to beam search

Comment: Just a follow up on my own comment: To counter the risk of error accumulation in time series forecasting (for which beam search cannot be applied), the concept of scheduled sampling can be used: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03099.pdf